# Pytorch BiDirectional RNN not working: RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (2, 76, 6), got (2, 500, 6)

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

```
class BiLSTMnetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, hidden_sz=6, p=0.5, out_features=2):
    #def __init__(self, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, vocab_size, target_size):
        super(BiLSTMnetwork, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_sz = hidden_sz

        self.in_features = in_features

        #Define the initial linear hidden layer
        #self.init_linear = nn.Linear(self.in_features, self.in_features)

        # The LSTM takes word embeddings as inputs, and outputs hidden states
        # with dimensionality hidden_dim.
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.in_features, hidden_sz,batch_first=True,bidirectional=True)

        # The linear layer that maps from hidden state space to tag space
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_sz*2, out_features)
      
        # Initialize h0 and c0:
        self.hidden = (torch.zeros(2,500,self.hidden_sz),
                       torch.zeros(2,500,self.hidden_sz))

    def forward(self,x):
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(
            x.view(len(x), 1, -1), self.hidden)



   # Can pass on the entirety of lstm_out to the next layer if it is a seq2seq prediction
    pred = self.linear(lstm_out.view(len(x),-1))
    y_val = F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1)
    return y_val

for _ in range(epochs):
    # using data_loader 
    for i, (data, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
        # Forward and get a prediction
        # x is the training data which is X_train
        if name.lower() == "rnn":
            model.hidden = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_sz),
                torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_sz))
        if name.lower() == "birnn":
            model.hidden = (torch.zeros(2,500,model.hidden_sz),
                torch.zeros(2,500,model.hidden_sz))
      
        y_pred = model.forward(data)
      
        # compute loss/error by comparing predicted out vs acutal labels
        loss = criterion(y_pred, labels)
        #losses.append(loss)
        
        if i%10==0:  # print out loss at every 10 epoch
            print(f'epoch {i} and loss is: {loss}')
        
        #Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
        optimizer.step()
```

hi all I am doing a BiDirectional RNN as seen above, as u can see the hidden state as been defined as (2,500,self.hidden_sz) , where self.hidden_sz = 6.

I ran the code and it managed to pass for the first 2 epoch, during the 3rd epoch and error popped up below. Really need ur help , my idea is this could be because of the bidirectional nature of BiRNN and hidden states cannot just be solely defined for 2 direction. Correct me if I am wrong , and help me with the code, thanks!

```
Running birnn classifier on dcuf.csv.gz features...
Evaluation 1
epoch 0 and loss is: 0.6595679521560669
epoch 10 and loss is: 0.6663855910301208
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dltanh.py", line 496, in <module>
    n_instances, n_features, scores = run_analysis()
  File "dltanh.py", line 361, in run_analysis
    y_pred = model.forward(data)
  File "dltanh.py", line 258, in forward
    x.view(len(x), 1, -1), self.hidden)
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 564, in forward
    return self.forward_tensor(input, hx)
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 543, in forward_tensor
    output, hidden = self.forward_impl(input, hx, batch_sizes, max_batch_size, sorted_indices)
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 523, in forward_impl
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 500, in check_forward_args
    'Expected hidden[0] size {}, got {}')
  File "/home/shar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 166, in check_hidden_size
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(expected_hidden_size, tuple(hx.size())))
RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (2, 76, 6), got (2, 500, 6)
(base) shar@smag3:~/msoftx/scriptx$
```

Answer (score 0):

for BiLSTM , got to set batch_first = False. Many thanks even though I don't know exactly why.